# Querying for data without scalar field

Tags: reactjs, go, graphql

I am new to Graphql and trying to implement a test query that calls a simple function on the backend.

This is the go function returning a simple string:

```
func (r *queryResolver) GetGoogleSheetData(ctx context.Context) (string, error) {
    var data string = "Hello Frontend"

    return data, nil
}
```

In React I'm using QueryRenderer to query for the data.

```
return (
        <QueryRenderer
                environment={environment}
                query={graphql`
                    query AwardGraphQuery {
                        GetGoogleSheetData {
                            // Should this be empty?
                        }
                    }
                `}
                variables={{}}
                render={({ error, props }: any) => {
                    if (error) return (
                        <Alert type="error">
                            {JSON.stringify(error, null, 2)}
                        </Alert>
                    );
                    if (!props) return <>No Data 1</>;
                    return props ? (
                        <h1>Test </h1>
                    ) : (
                        <>
                            <div>Loading</div>
                        </>
                    )
                }}
          />
    )
```

Since the backend function always returns the same string, I thought I simply had to omit everything in GetGoogleSheetData:

```
GetGoogleSheetData {
    // Should this be empty?
}
```

I get this Error:

```
ERROR:
Parse error: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Should this be empty?

No it shouldn't, as the error says

> Parse error: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found }

It should include the `Name`

```
GetGoogleSheetData {
    Name
}
```

Would need to know the rest of the definition for that query to provide a final answer, but yes it seems that field is required.